# MySql: Selecting records starting with "\" character

Tags: mysql, escaping

I have a `student` table in which there is `description` column. Now I want to select all records which are having '\' (backslash) in `description`.
Now if I am correct according to [special character sequence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) "\\" represents "\".

But query as follow does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE description LIKE '%\\%'
```

And following queries are working:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE description LIKE '%\\\%'

SELECT * FROM student WHERE description LIKE '%\\\\%'
```

So I just don't know how `MySql` is evaluating it.

Comment: how are you sending the query to mysql? If you're using a language like PHP and the query is in a string, then you need to be aware of the string escaping for that lanauge, which may also require backslashes to be escaped.

Comment: Nope, that's wrong - see the multiple answers below which explain the reason why multiple slashes are required. And [read the right manual section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) !! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE description LIKE '%\\\%'
```

You need two levels of escaping: one for the string literal, and another for the LIKE pattern.

This also works:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE description LIKE '%\\\\%';
```

The first one works because `\%` is not an escape sequence, so the backslash is left in. The second works because the second `\\` is another escaped backslash, which becomes a single backslash.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984a6/3)

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

As a workaround to keep only the "parser backslash stripping", use the following syntax:

```
select * from T where s like "%\\%" escape "#";
```

(I use here `#` but any other char not present in your query string will be acceptable for *escape*).

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa5d9/5

Answer (score 0):

See the first "Note" here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\\n”. To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Comment: snap! :-P (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.
>
> Exception: At the end of the pattern string, backslash can be
>   specified as “\”. At the end of the string, backslash stands for
>   itself because there is nothing following to escape. Suppose that a
>   table contains the following values:

Answer (score 0):

First you have to escape the \ literal. With like you have to escape the escaped literal as well. See examples below:

Only one escaping needed for the regular expression:

```
select * from student where test_char REGEXP "[\\]+";
```

One extra escaping is needed for the LIKE:

```
select * from student where test_char LIKE '%\\\%'
```